# How to clean a working SSD, repartition and reinstall Windows 10

Tags: ssd

I'm trying to fix GPT Partition name corruption from cloning HDD to SSD using Todo EaseUS (what a mistake that was!). The system works, but generates XML script errors when doing disk image backup (2155348129). I can boot to the SSD, but if I select to boot from the HDD the SSD no longer shows in Device Manager, Disk Manager or diskpart even though it is detected in BIOS.

If I could get it to show up, I could use diskpart to clean & repartition either while running Windows from the HDD or with the HDD disconnected from a Windows installation usb drive. Alternatively, if I could find the source for the XML script data element GptName I might be able to edit. Is it in the registry?

Comment: If you want to start over, simply zero out the first 63 sectors (the first "track") of the drive using the Linux `dd` command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download some kind of Linux live ISO (I prefer [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Download/)), burn it to a DVD(RW) and boot it.
2. Identify the SSD with `blkid`. Sample output:

   ```
   sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
   ├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part
   └─sda2   8:2    0 232,4G  0 part
   sdb      8:16   0   2,7T  0 disk 
   ├─sdb1   8:17   0    16G  0 part
   └─sdb2   8:18   0   2,7T  0 part
   sr0     11:0    1 669,8M  0 rom
   ```

   In this case, my SSD is `sda` (it has ~250G of space, seen in the third column).
3. Open parted (substitute sda with your device identifier):

   ```
   # parted /dev/sda
   GNU Parted 3.2
   Using /dev/sda
   Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
   (parted)
   ```
4. Type in `mklabel gpt`. This will create a new GPT partition table. (All your data on that drive will be lost!)
5. Quit out of parted by typing in `quit` and then type `reboot` to reboot the system.
6. Now you should be able to install Windows on that partition without any errors!